# perl compiler or packer that tolerate perl fork in windows plateform

Tags: cygwin, fork, activeperl, pp-perl-par-packager

If Perl code use fork or its variant like Paralell::Loops or Parallel::ForkManager, pp from Par::Packer generated standalone exe will crash when run, see example in https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/perl.par/U4HbbbcRRTQ. B::C or B::CC are also tested not working in such cases: activeperl can't even install it,show error like:

C.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol Perl_Iwatchaddr_ptr
C.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol Perl_Iwatchok_ptr

cygwin perl can install and generate exe as instructed in https://github.com/rurban/perl-compiler, but when we run it, it crashes with error like *END failed--call queue abortedCouldn't print to pipe*. Are there some tested working Perl compiler or packer that would work for fork?

Answer (score 0):

Enclose all the code inside END {}, and change the *use* to *require*, like *require Parallel::Loops*. For those implicity dependance module, explicitly include them in pp, for example:

```
pp -M Params::Validate::XS -M Params::Validate::PP -M Class/Load/XS.pm -M Class/Load/PP.pm -o some-code.exe some-code.pl
```

If the script do not need to share data between the parent and the children, we can also use MCE, which have a [*use threads*](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=85862) option that is compatible with pp and we do not need the END {} method.